# incorrect run php by button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have php function which update all records in data table and need it run by click button in html.

My php function look like this:

```
<?php
try {
  $sql = 'SELECT id_data, date_record, value1, value2, value3 FROM data ';
  $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $s->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  $error = 'Error with select data' . $e->getMessage();
  include 'error.html.php';
  exit();
}

while ($row = $s->fetch()) {
  $dane[] = array(
    'id_data' => $row['id_data'],
    'date_record' => $row['date_record'],
    'value1' => $row['value1'],
    'value2' => $row['value2'],
    'value3' => $row['value3']
  );
}


if (isset($_GET['edytion'])) {
  foreach ($data as $data2) {
    try {
      $sql = 'UPDATE data SET date_record = :date_record, value1 = :value1, value2 = :value2, value3 = :value3 WHERE id_data= :id_data';
      $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
      $s->bindValue(':date_record', $_POST['date_record']);
      $s->bindValue(':value1', $_POST['value1']);
      $s->bindValue(':value2', $_POST['value2']);
      $s->bindValue(':value3', $_POST['value3']);
      $s->bindValue(':id_data', $_POST['id_data']);
      $s->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      $error = 'Edit data error  ' . $e->getMessage();
      include 'error.html.php';
      exit();
    }
  }

  Header("Location: theme3.php");
}
?>
```

And my form in html where i try run this look:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Value 1</th>
        <th>Value 2</th>
        <th>Value 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php if (isset($data)): ?>
      <?php foreach ($data as $data1): $a = 0 ?>
        <form action="?edytion" method="post" id='ed'>
          <tr class="bg-primary">
            <input type="hidden"  name="id_data" id="id_data" value="<?php echo $data1['id_data']; ?>">
            <td><input type="date"  name="date_record" id="date_record" value="<?php echo $data1['date_record']; ?>"> </td>
            <td><input type="text"  name="value1" id="value1" value="<?php echo $data1['value1']; ?>"> </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="value2" id="value2" value="<?php echo $data1['value2']; ?>"> </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="value3" id="value3" value="<?php echo $data1['value3']; ?>"> </td>
            <!-- <input type="hidden" ondblclick="default" id="id_buttona" value="Edit"/> -->
          </tr>
        </form>
        <?php $a++;
      endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" id="id_buttona" onclick="document.getElementById('ed').submit();" value="Edit"/>
</div>
```

Ultimately when i try update data it update only first record in table, rest of them is invariable.
Anybody know what is wrong and have idea how correct it? I will be grateful for help!

Comment: show your js code also

Comment: show your php, html view, and js code properly, it looks incomplete

Comment: Where is your submit function which you used in `onclick="document.getElementById('ed').submit();"`?

Comment: Chris i check this result and it write all id_data correctly

Comment: Nana I dont have submit function, i was thinking it was buitd in <form> specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create too many forms with the same `id`. Surround the table with the `<form>` and do `foreach` on `<tr>` only.
Something like this

```
<div class="table-responsive">
 <form action="?edytion" method="post" id='ed'>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Value 1</th>
        <th>Value 2</th>
        <th>Value 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php if (isset($data)): ?>
      <?php $a = 0; foreach ($data as $data1): ?>

          <tr class="bg-primary">
            <input type="hidden"  name="id_data<?php echo $a; ?>" id="id_data" value="<?php echo $data1['id_data']; ?>" />
            <td><input type="date" name="date_record<?php echo $a; ?>" value="<?php echo $data1['date_record']; ?>"> </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="value1<?php echo $a; ?>" value="<?php echo $data1['value1']; ?>"> </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="value2<?php echo $a; ?>" value="<?php echo $data1['value2']; ?>"> </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="value3<?php echo $a; ?>" value="<?php echo $data1['value3']; ?>"> </td>
          </tr>

        <?php $a++;
      endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input name="row_count" value="<?php echo isset($a) ? $a : 0; ?>" type="hidden"/>
  </form>
  <input type="submit" id="id_buttona" onclick="document.getElementById('ed').submit();" value="Edit"/>
</div>
```

The way you created each form for each row will not work well because: (1) all your forms have the same javascript `id`, when you do `getElementById` only the first form is affected, (2) when you submit that one form the page reloads and all the changes to other rows are lost.
One solution is to make only 1 form and have different name to all fields. Forms fields are sent by `name` and `value` so you need different names for all fields and you don't really need ids.

You can add row count somewhere in the form and then change php to something like this:

```
$row_count = $_POST['row_count'];
for($i = 0; i < $row_count; i++) {
try {
            $sql = 'UPDATE data SET
                            date_record = :date_record,
                            value1 = :value1,
                            value2 = :value2,
                            value3 = :value3
                         WHERE id_data= :id_data';

            $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $s->bindValue(':date_record', $_POST['date_record' . $i]);
            $s->bindValue(':value1', $_POST['value1' . $i]);
            $s->bindValue(':value2', $_POST['value2' . $i]);
            $s->bindValue(':value3', $_POST['value3' . $i]);
            $s->bindValue(':id_data', $_POST['id_data' . $i]);
            $s->execute();
        } 
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            $error = 'Edit data error  ' . $e->getMessage();
            include 'error.html.php';
            exit();
        }
  }
```

Comment: It will not work because in loop a send every change in forms depending on id_data. When i do one form button dont update.

Comment: You'll need to change the names of input fields in each iteration. You can concatenate the `$a` variable to the input name. You don't use that variable right now. You'll need to change the php on the server side accordingly.

Comment: I remove $a and incrementation

Comment: But i noticed when i dependence form id  from $data1['id_data'] like this:

   
 <form action="?edytion" method="post" id='<?php echo $data1['id_data']; ?>'> 

And in input submit induce: 
<input type="submit" id="id_buttona" onclick="document.getElementById('<?php echo $data1[id_data]; ?>').submit();" value="Edit"/>


Then it will hange last index. But how induce all id_data array?

Comment: You can make few forms with different `id`s but you'll need a submit button for each form. Also this does not solve the problem number (2) in my answer; you'll lose changes to other forms when you submit one form. And you can only submit one form at a time.

Comment: So how is the best way to solve this? I suspect i should change php implementation, but how when i want change all records in table?

Comment: But it still don't working and don't update table, first -  it don't increase     
`$a` variable.

Comment: Yeah. I forgot to move `$a=0;` outside of `foreach` loop.

Comment: Now it change only last record in table. But when i '<?php echo $a; ?>'  it shows me 0 all the time

Comment: Now it work!! Thank you very very very much!! :) :) :) :)

Comment: @Monika you are welcome. Accept and upvote the answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

It is all html file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tematyka2</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>



</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="heading"></div>
    <table border="0" width="766" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">

        <tr>
            <td class="t1"><p>Example title</p></td><td class="t2"> <a href="logout.php"><b class="linkW" style="padding-left: 60%">Logout</b></a></td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td class="top1"><div class="inscription">Your Page</div></td>
            <td class="top2" valign="top"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>


    <table align="center" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr><td class="topm">Main menu</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="tlom">
                        :: <a href="index.php">Main page</a> <br>
                        </td></tr>

                    <tr><td class="dolm"></td></tr
                </table>

                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr><td class="topm">Them</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="tlom">
                            :: <a href="them1.php">Them 1</a> <br>
                            :: <a href="them2.php"><b>Them 2</b></a> <br>
                            :: <a href="them3.php">Them 3</a> <br>
                        </td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="dolm"></td></tr
                </table>


                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr><td class="topm">Charts</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="tlom">
                            :: <a href="">Chart1</a> <br>
                            :: <a href="">Chart2</a> <br>
                        </td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="dolm"></td></tr>
                </table>


                <br>
            </td>






            <td width="1"></td>
            <td valign="top">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr><td class="topn"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="tlon">


                            <div class="span7 center">
                                <h2>
                                    EDYTION
                                </h2>
                            </div>

                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Date</th>
                                        <th>Value 1</th>
                                        <th>Value 2</th>
                                        <th>Value 3</th>

                                    </tr>

                                    </thead>


                                    <?php if(isset($data)): ?>
                                        <?php foreach($data as $data1): $a=0?>
                                            <form action="?edytion" method="post" id='ed'>

                                                <tr class="bg-primary">


                                                    <input type="hidden"  name="id_data" id="id_data" value="<?php echo $data1['id_data']; ?>">
                                                    <td><input type="date"  name="date_record" id="date_record" value="<?php echo $data1['date_record']; ?>"> </td>
                                                    <td><input type="text"  name="value1" id="value1" value="<?php echo $data1['value1']; ?>"> </td>
                                                    <td><input type="text" name="value2" id="value2" value="<?php echo $data1['value2']; ?>"> </td>
                                                    <td><input type="text" name="value3" id="value3" value="<?php echo $data1['value3']; ?>"> </td>
                                                   <!-- <input type="hidden" ondblclick="default" id="id_buttona" value="Edit"/> -->

                                                </tr>

                                            </form>
                                        <?php $a++; endforeach; ?>

                                    <?php endif; ?>





                                    </tbody>
                                </table>



                                <input type="submit" id="id_buttona" onclick="document.getElementById('ed').submit();" value="Edit"/>


                            </div>


                    </td></tr>
                <!--  <tr><td class="doln"></td></tr> -->
            </table>
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="foot1"> My page</td>
        <td class="foot2"><a href="" title="szablony"><img src="images/dol2.jpg" alt="anything"></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And Php part:

```
<?php

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/connection_to_database.php';

include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/check_login.php';      try {
        $sql = 'SELECT id_data, date_record, value1, value2, value3 FROM data ';

        $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error = 'Error with select data' . $e->getMessage();
        include 'error.html.php';
        exit();
    }

    while ($row = $s->fetch()) {
        $dane[] = array(
            'id_data' => $row['id_data'],
            'date_record' => $row['date_record'],
            'value1' => $row['value1'],
            'value2' => $row['value2'],
            'value3' => $row['value3']
        );
    }



    if (isset($_GET['edytion'])) {


        foreach ($data as $data2) {


            try {
                $sql = 'UPDATE data SET
                                date_record = :date_record,
                                value1 = :value1,
                                value2 = :value2,
                                value3 = :value3
                             WHERE id_data= :id_data';

                $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $s->bindValue(':date_record', $_POST['date_record']);
                $s->bindValue(':value1', $_POST['value1']);
                $s->bindValue(':value2', $_POST['value2']);
                $s->bindValue(':value3', $_POST['value3']);
                $s->bindValue(':id_data', $_POST['id_data']);
                $s->execute();
            } 
            catch (PDOException $e) {
                $error = 'Edit data error  ' . $e->getMessage();
                include 'error.html.php';
                exit();
            }


        }

        Header("Location: theme3.php");

    }

?>
```

And that's all about update data. Php and html are in one file, I know it's look unprofessionally and i shoudln't do it in this way.

Comment: Just an aside note, you shouldn't post additional code in an answer, just edit the initial question instead